# R2 (R Square) Negative for timeseries using LSTM & GRU

Tags: python, lstm

I have tried some case for time series analysis using LSTM & GRU,
but i got a value for R2 is negative, but the prediction of graph is good.

Maybe someone knows why?

What does it means? some reference said, R2 is between 0 & +1.
Thank you.

Edit : Here's my code using r2_score from sklearn.metrics

```
# Evaluating the model
def evaluate_model(model,test,timesteps):
  X_test = []
  Y_test = []

  # Loop for testing data
  for i in range(timesteps,test.shape[0]):
      X_test.append(test[i-timesteps:i])
      Y_test.append(test[i][6]) # Index 6 (CLOSE) for outcome /output y-axis
  X_test,Y_test = np.array(X_test), np.array(Y_test)

  # Prediction Time !!!!
  Y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
  mse = mean_squared_error(Y_test,Y_hat)
  rmse = sqrt(mse)
  r = r2_score(Y_test,Y_hat)
  return  mse, rmse, r, Y_test, Y_hat

# Picking the multivariate series 
variables = ['Open','High','Low','PER', 'PBV', 'ROE', 'Close'] #Close on -1 or 6th index
series = df[variables] 

import datetime as dt
# Note : 2017-12-22 00:00:00 until 2020-12-30 00:00:00 
# Train Data
train_start = dt.date(2017,12,22)
train_end = dt.date(2020,1,17)
train_data = series.loc[train_start:train_end] # Output Train Data

# Validation Data
val_start = dt.date(2020,1,18)
val_end = dt.date(2020,9,6)
val_data = series.loc[val_start:val_end] # Output Validation Data

# Test Data
test_start = dt.date(2020,9,7)
test_end = dt.date(2020,12,30)
test_data = series.loc[test_start:test_end] # Output Test Data

print(f"Data train {train_start}:{train_end}")
print(f"Data validation {val_start}:{val_end}")
print(f"Data test {test_start}:{test_end}")
print()
print(train_data.shape,val_data.shape,test_data.shape)

# ROT: 70-20-10

model, train_error, val_error, history = fit_model(train, val, timesteps, hl, lr, batch_size, num_epochs) #training
plot_error(train_error,val_error)
```

#### And here's the measurement results

```
mse, rmse, r2_value, true,predicted = evaluate_model(model, test, timesteps)
print('MSE = {}'.format(mse))
print('RMSE = {}'.format(rmse))
print('R-Squared Score = {}'.format(r2_value))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if we had a bit more to go on! Which packages are you using, which functions, how are you using them? A reproducible example would be good too.

Comment: A negative R2 can happen if the fitted model is worse than the null model (the arithmetic average). R2 for ordinary linear models is between 0 and 1, but for nonlinear models it can be between -Inf and 1. If, however, the "graph is good" then you have probably a programming error. And, if it is a time series, it can also happen that you have a time shift, i.e. the prediction does not really look good.

Comment: @AndrewGustar sorry, i resend my code.

Comment: @tpetzoldt LSTM/GRU isn't a non linear models ? yes, i have a timesteps variables for that

Comment: **lstm** is definitely not an ordinary linear model and your code is not **R** as the tag suggests. I recommend to add the **python** tag.